# Ob beide Fragen richtig sind

Tags: word-usage

Um herauszufinden, in welche Richtung ein Wegweiser zeigt, kann man die beide Fragen stellen?

> Wonach zeigt der Wegweiser?

und

> Wohin zeigt der Wegweiser?

Comment: Eine sprachliche Bemerkung zu deinem Fragetitel: Es ist auf Deutsch eher unüblich, Satzfragmente mit "ob ..." alleinstehend zu verwenden, nicht einmal, wenn kein vollständiger Satz gebildet werden soll. Normalerweise schreibt man in solch einem Fall als Überschrift entweder direkt die Frage ("Sind beide Fragen richtig?") oder man fügt etwas hinzu, was das "ob"-Konstrukt ergänzt ("Frage, ob beide Fragen richtig sind"; "Unklar, ob beide Fragen richtig sind"). Als weitere Alternative könnte man eventuell noch auf ein Substantiv ausweichen ("Richtigkeit beider Fragen").

Comment: Es ist natürlich schwierig, im Titel einen präzisen Hinweis auf die ganze Frage zu geben - aber der obige Titel ist nun wirklich völlig nichtssagend.

Answer (score 1):

Können tut man schon, aber richtig ist nur die zweite Variante. Die erste ist falsch und wird vermutlich auch nur von wenigen so verstanden wie sie vermutlich gemeint ist.

### wonach

Das Pronomialadverb *»wonach«* kann interrogativ oder relativ verwendet werden:

- interrogativ (fragend)
  Wenn das Wort *»wonach«* in einer Frage verwendet wird, bedeutet es *»nach welcher Sache«:*

  > **Wonach** suchst du?
  > **Nach welcher Sache** suchst du?

  > **Wonach** hat er dich gefragt?
  > **Nach welcher Sache** hat er dich gefragt?

  > **Wonach** steht dir heute der Sinn?
  > **Nach welcher Sache** steht dir heute der Sinn?

  Aber das folgende Beispiel ergibt keinen Sinn:

  > <del>***Wonach** zeigt der Wegweiser?*</del>
  > <del>***Nach welcher Sache** zeigt der Wegweiser?*</del>
- relativ (einen Relativsatz einleitend)
  Wenn mit dem Wort *»wonach«* ein Relativsatz eingeleitet wird, bezieht sich der Relativsatz auf den Wortlaut einer Aussage:

  > Die Meldung, **wonach** das Handy des Bundeskanzlers beschlagnahmt worden sei, erwies sich als wahr.

  Hier sagt der Relativsatz (der Teil des Satzes, der zwischen den beiden Kommas steht) aus, was der Wortlaut der Meldung war.

  Relativsätze, die mit *»wonach«* eingeleitet werden, beziehen sich daher immer auf Wörter wie *»Meldung«, »Bericht«, »Zeitungsartikel«, »Radiosendung«* usw.

### wohin

Dieses Wort ist ebenfalls ein Pronomialadverb, und es kann ebenso interrogativ und relativ verwendet werden, hat aber immer einen streng lokalen Bezug, das heißt, es kann nicht temporal oder modal verwendet werden.

- interrogativ (fragend)
  Wenn das Wort *»wohin«* in einer Frage verwendet wird, bedeutet es *»in welche Richtung«* oder *»an/auf/in welche(n) Ort/Platz/Stelle«:*

  > **Wohin** gehst du?
  > **In welche Richtung** gehst du?

  > **Wohin** soll ich die Vase stellen?
  > **An welche Stelle** soll ich die Vase stellen?
  > **Auf welchen Platz** soll ich die Vase stellen?

  Daher auch:

  > **Wohin** zeigt der Wegweiser?
  > **In welche Richtung** zeigt der Wegweiser?
- relativ (einen Relativsatz einleitend)
  Wenn mit dem Wort *»wohin«* ein Relativsatz eingeleitet wird, bezieht sich der Relativsatz auf eine Richtung oder einen Zielort:

  > Ich folge dir, **wohin** du auch gehst.

  Hier beschreibt der Relativsatz das Ziel einer Reise.
- umgangssprachlich
  Bei der dritten Möglichkeit, das Wort *»wohin«* zu verwenden, bedeutet dieses Wort *»auf die Toilette«:*

  > Ich muss mal **wohin.**
  > Ich muss mal **auf die Toilette.**

Answer (score 0):

Nein, die erste Variante ist dafür nicht korrekt. Die zweite Variante ist eindeutig und gibt den Zweck der Frage gut wieder.

Andere, einfach formulierte, auch nicht so gute Varianten:

> Nach wo zeigt der Wegweiser?
>
> Wo lang zeigt der Wegweiser?

*Wohin* bezieht sich eindeutig auf einen Ort / ein Ziel, also eine absolute Angabe.

*Wonach* ist für Ortsangaben relativ zu sehen und kann für örtliche Abfolgen verwendet werden.

> Wo(nach) soll ich abbiegen? 300 Meter nach der Ampel.

Kommt man aber aus der anderen Richtung, ist es 300 Meter vor der Ampel.

Seltener sind es auch zeitliche Abfolgen:

> Wonach spielt die Musik? Die Musik wird nach dem Essen gespielt.

*Wonach* wird auch verwendet für Objekte.

> Wonach soll ich suchen?